# C++ how to call Base class method from multiple derived class?

Tags: c++

I have a Base and multiple derived class as below.

```
class Base
{
 public:
   virtual bool add(int); //has defined in BaseA.cpp
    ...
};
class DerivedA: protected Base
{
 public:
    ...
}
class DerivedB: public DerivedA
{
 public:
    void test();
    ...
}
```

How do I call `add()` method which is in `Base` class in `DerivedB` class method?

```
 void DerivedB::test(){
    Base::add(10);
 }
```

When I do the above it is failing saying "Undefined reference".

Thanks

Comment: Did you even define the base class method?

Comment: [It works well without any errors.](http://ideone.com/P9ydcZ) I guess maybe `obj` is missing >o<

Comment: Btw, why do you use protected inheritance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You're calling it correctly.**

What you're missing, as the error message suggests, is a *definition* for `Base::add(int)`.

Basically you need to link BaseA.cpp.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is correct. If you are getting undefined reference it means the error is at linking stage. This can happen for three reasons:

1. The .cpp file ( in your case BaseA.cpp ) is not getting compiled. If you are using Eclipse CDT then the utility will auto compile all the source files but if you have your own makefile or you are compiling the files manually, then ensure that all the .cc files are getting compiled correctly.
2. The .cpp file is getting compiled but is not getting linked. Check the command where final executable is getting created and ensure that all the .o files are being used.
3. You have not provided a definition for the add function of Base in BaseA.cpp file.

I compiled a test program with your code and it runs fine if all the above conditions are satisfied.

Hope this helps.